# Search for select options in CakePHP 3 using FriendsOfCake/search plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, search, plugins, cakephp-3.x

I am using the search plugin for CakePHP 3 from [FriendsOfCake](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) and I am trying to search for select options.

View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('worker_id', [
        'multiple' => true,
        'options' => $workers,
        'label' => ['text' => __('Worker: ')],
    ]);
```

Table:

```
$this->searchManager()
   ->add('worker_id', 'Search.Value');
```

Now whenever I select an option in the view, it appends `%5B0%5D` to the url which stands for `[0]`, e.g.

```
http://localhost/customers?worker_id%5B0%5D=23
```

When I remove `%5B0%5D` from the url, the correct results are shown. How can I prevent this from being added to the url automatically?

Comment: And you _really_ want to allow multiple selections?

Comment: If that is the issue I could drop this feature...

Comment: It kinda is, most probably, as this is currently not supported, however I can't really tell if that's a bug. Multiple values will conflict with the aliased filter support feature (`Table.field`).

Comment: See also **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/issues/77**